# PrestaShop WebServices Add address

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im having problem with creating new addres via WebServices
Im using PrestaShop 1.6.0.14 and PSWebServiceLibrary
Here is my code:

```
                    try
                    {
                        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
                        $xml = $webService->get( array( 'url' => 'http://raj-dla-ogrodu.pl/api/addresses?schema=blank' ) );
                        $resources = $xml->children()->children();
                        $infos = array(
                            'id_customer' => '50',
                            'id_country' => '14',
                            'id_state' => '0',
                            'alias' => 'Allegro',
                            'id_manufacturer' => '0',
                            'id_supplier' => '0',
                            'id_warehouse' => '0',
                            'deleted' => '0',
                            'lastname' => 'test',
                            'firstname' => 'test',
                            'address1' => 'Klient',
                            'address2' => '111',
                            'postcode' => $transakcje->RecipientZip,
                            'city' => 'test',
                            'phone_mobile' => $transakcje->RecipientPhone,
                            'phone' => $transakcje->RecipientPhone,

                            );
                        foreach ($resources as $nodeKey => $node)
                        {
                            $resources->$nodeKey = $infos[$nodeKey];
                        }
                        $opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
                         $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
                         $xml = $webService->add($opt);
                    }
                    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
                    {
                    }
```

Im getting that Bad Response error. Any clues What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try the `url` from browser if it is correct with few parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the line `$opt = array('resource' => 'customers');` with `$opt = array('resource' => 'addresses');`